# Function that refuses to return a value

Tags: functions, evaluation

I wanted to know the exact solution to the following differential equation

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d} t^2} = - \frac{1}{y-1}, \quad \begin{aligned} y(0) &= 0 \\ \left. \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} t} \right|_{t = 0} &= 0 \end{aligned}
$$

I expected some function that would increase with time until it hits one.

So I set up the DE in MMA

```
ClearAll[y];
DSolve[{y''[t] == -(1/(y[t] - 1)), y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, y[t], t]
```

And the result is

```
{y[t] -> E^-InverseErf[-Sqrt[(2/\[Pi])] t]^2 (-1 + E^
     InverseErf[-Sqrt[(2/\[Pi])] t]^2)}
```

So I try to plot it with derivatives

```
y[t] := E^-InverseErf[-Sqrt[(2/\[Pi])] t]^2 (-1 + E^
     InverseErf[-Sqrt[(2/\[Pi])] t]^2);
Plot[Evaluate[{y[t], 1/(y[t] - 1), D[y[t], t], D[y[t], {t, 2}]}], {t, 
  0, 2}]
```

And everything goes fine.

However, when I'm trying to obtain the value at which the function stops (I think it is $t = \sqrt{\pi/2}$), MMA doesn't know

```
Solve[y[t] == 1, t]
{}
```

When I tried to get certain values, MMA doesn't even return a number!

```
y[0.5]
y[0.5]
```

or

```
Evaluate[y[0.5]]
y[0.5]
```

Clearly, the plot behaves well around $t = 0.5$, so why does it refuse to return a value?

The only thing that seems to work is the following

```
y[t] /. t -> 0.5
0.12777
```

Can someone please explain this behaviour? I am curious.

Comment: Simply `y[t_] :=....`, i.e. use the underscore in defining the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write:

```
y[t]:=rhs
```

That means, "when you see `y[t]`, rewrite it as `rhs` and continue evaluating. Here, `t` is just a literal symbol, not an argument, so `y[anything but t]` doesn't match and nothing happens. But:

```
y[t_]:=rhs
```

is very different. Here, `t` is the name of a pattern, unrestricted in this case, so it matches anything at all. The rewrite here starts by rewriting every `t` in rhs by whatever matched the pattern. The result replaces `y[whatever]`, and evaluation continues. This is how *Mathematica*, an expression rewriting language, imitates a function call.

Comment: Thank you very much! That might explain why the ./t-> thing worked!